# Rails 4 has many through and order scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, -> { order('customers.name ASC') }
  has_many :stores, -> { order('company_stores.id ASC').uniq }, through: :customers
end
```

When I attempt to

```
user.stores
```

I have this error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

because Rails performs a `SELECT DISTINCT of company_stores.*`, but in the `ORDER BY` also appears `customers.name`

Should I give up order in associations?

Comment: what's the relationship between stores and customers? probably easier to post your schema, and also post the SQL query that is resulting in that error.

Comment: alternatively, the solution will probably be as simple as adding `select('stores.*, company_stores.id')` to your scope, couldn't be 100% sure though.

Comment: thanks, I solved with `has_many :stores, -> { select('company_stores.*, customers.name').order('company_stores.id ASC').uniq }, through: :customers` please leave the answer below and I'll accept it.

Comment: Also see, * https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5701
* https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13677

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message suggests, PG requires that the order expression is included in the select, so `select('stores.*, company_stores.id').order('company_stores.id ASC').uniq` or similar should do the trick.